# How to store media files into MediaStore

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I'm trying  to develop a video player on the  Android TV. 
I couldn't get the media files in USB device through the Android media provider. 
I tried to use the MediaScannerConnectionClient to scan the USB device directory but it seems not worked.
Can you tell me how to store the USB media files into Media provider  And how to access them?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the function:

```
public class MediaScannerWrapper implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

     private MediaScannerConnection mConnection;
     private String mPath;
     private String mMimeType;

     public MediaScannerWrapper(Context ctx, String filePath, String mime){
         mPath = filePath;
         mMimeType = mime;
         mConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(ctx, this);
     }

     public void scan(){
         mConnection.connect();
     }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mConnection.scanFile(mPath, mMimeType);
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Media file scanned: "+mPath);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String arg0, Uri arg1) {
    }

}
```

and then try:

```
new MediaScannerWrapper(ctx, mostRecentRecording.getFullPath(), "audio/*").scan();
ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + PathsHandler.getInstance().getRecordingsDirectory())));
```

Comment: The second parameter of MediaScannerWrapper(): String  filePath, can this path be a directory? In my situation, this should be "/mnt/sda/sda4"(the USB device directory ).
And I have no idea about the second parameter when sendbroadcast   Uri in my situation.

Comment: My platform is android 4.4 and it is not allowed to send broadcast MEDIA_MOUNTED